# После обновления с ubuntu 16.04 server до ubuntu 18.04 server перестал раздавать интернет в локальную сеть

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, nat

У меня есть сервер в нем стоит две сетевые карты. который работает как роутер для раздачи интернета в локальную сеть и как веб-хостинг. К одной приходит интернет от провайдера по dhcp интерфейс em1, вторая static интерфейс em2 раздает интернет в локальную сеть.

После обновления с ubuntu 16.04 server до ubuntu 18.04 server перестал раздавать интернет в локальную сеть.

Настройки не изменились, проверил /etc/nat, но раздача не работает.

Comment: Проверьте iptables

Comment: DHCP сервис на em2 присутствовал? Каким образом ваши локальные хосты получали IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переустановил на ubuntu server 18.04 но там новые вопросы появились - 
Смена МАС адреса Ubuntu Server 18.04 (netplan)
Теперь пишут что нужно все делать через /etc/netplan